# Is it okay to pass React elements as a prop value of another component for it to render them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I have a question while using reactjs.

1. Declares a variable (?) that has a B component in the Render part of the A class component.
2. In return, bind the variable to the proxy of the C component.
3. Rendering in C Component.

--> Is this way have any problem in reactjs?

```
class A extends Component{
 .....
 render() {
  const detail = (
    <B
      contents={[
         {
            title: <div style={{ wordBreak: 'keep-all' }}>foo</div>,
            child: (
              <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <div style={{ marginRight: '-10px' }}>
            ....
      })
  )
  return(
    <C
      detailCompo={detail}
     />
  );
 }
}


// in C component

class C extends Component {
 ....
 render() {
  return(
   {this.props.detailCompo}
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: If it works well, it's okay.

Comment: No, it's not conventional if that's what you're asking.  Passing an array of objects that contain markup is (your `contents` prop) is not the right way to get to your eventual render.  You want to pass data (props) to your final render.  You may also want to look at HOCs.  https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do, but yes, it's a valid way to render JSX. I've seen similar components that needs pre-translated content, sometimes in objects. If it's clear to you and your team, that's what matter.

Comment: If it works, its ok. But there other techniques that you could use to achieve what you are trying to make. You could make use a bunch of react functionalities to improve your code quality

Comment: @Ange I'd like to improve code quality, but can you help me find out what search word?

Comment: @Woooong for one, you can look up compound components. Basically, you don't have to pass down a component using props (although it will still work), what you could do is pass it down as children of component C like ```<C > <DetailComponent /> </C>``` (this is just one way)